# Hive create -ext-10000 subfolder

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs, orc

When we try to insert overwrite hive table, hive create subfolder -ext-10000.
Data in these table become invisible for Spark.
Only table with low rows have these problems.

spark version: version 3.1.1
hive version: Hive 3.1.0.3.1.4.0-315

We try to set

```
"hive.input.dir.recursive" = "TRUE"
"hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories" = "TRUE"
"hive.supports.subdirectories" = "TRUE"
"mapred.input.dir.recursive" = "TRUE"
```

and it takes not affect

query example:

```
insert overwrite table categories
select
    n2.id as category1_ccode
    ,n2.name as category1_name
    ,n3.id as category2_ccode
    ,n3.name as category2_name
from nomenclature as n1
left join nomenclature as n2
    on n1.id = n2.parent_id
left nomenclature as n3
    on n2.id = n3.parent_id
where
    n1.name = 'Goods'
    and n1.delete_mark = '00'
    and n2.delete_mark = '00'
    and n3.delete_mark = '00'
    and n1.is_group = '00'
    and n2.is_group = '00';
```

Files stores in ORC format

Comment: Please provide query which creates subfolders. Is it a UNION query?

Comment: it's not a union query (query example in a body now)

Comment: interesting what can cause this behavior... Is the table created with STORED AS DIRECTORIES in DDL? or SKEWED. Have never seen such behavior in Hive

Comment: No, it's not skewed or stored as directories.